# Trouble converting SQL Query to LINQ?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I need some help converting the SQL found below to an equivalent LINQ statement in C# assuming that I am using the EF also.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ProductID],[NumberOfMixes]
  FROM [EPOS_DB].[dbo].[Combinations]
  WHERE NumberOfMixes != 1
  Group By ProductID, NumberOfMixes
```

The sql above is producing the correct number of results for me. I just want to wrap .Count().ToString method around a LINQ statement to produce a numeric valued stored in a string. That is all I need.

Comment: Why do you need the grouping if you already grab only distinct elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var count = context.Combinations
                   .Where( x=> x.NumberOfMixes!=1)
                   .Select( x=> new { x.ProductId, x.NumberOfMixes })
                   .Distinct()
                   .Count();
```